# Project in the work space

Tags: android, workspace

i made some changes to the class clockwork in the project and it showed no mistakes but when i try to run it i says there are some mistakes in the project .is the project corrupt ? 
if it is corrupted are there any ways to restore the project ? all the other projects in the work space run correctly. is there a mistake in the code ? manifest file is fine.

i have spent a lot of time on it, don't wanna lose it.
any help is appreciated .

[image]

Comment: Does your Problem pane in Eclispse show any error-warning? In your snapshot the problems pane is marked with red but you clipped it. Anyway, you should try to project->clean to get a new clean compilation.

Answer (score -1):

i actually changed the workspace and imported the project into it and it worked